# Deleting all firebase data and references then deleting permissions

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I have an angular code with many directives and scopes, each of them having it's own references to firebase data. I use custom authentication and store permissions on firebase itself.

My problem is: at some point I need to delete data, then after deleting it I also need to delete the related permissions. All this works fine on the database and on the UI, but I get a bunch of permission errors on console, probably because some scopes are still referencing the deleted data.

I noticed I could use .$destroy() to clear the reference and it worked, but it would polute my code to include .$destroy()s all over.

Are there any patterns that I might be missing to handle this kind of situation? To give a better notion, my firebase data is structured like the following:

```
<account id>
    permissions
        <house id>
            owner: {r: 1, w: 1},
            admin: {r: 1, w: 0}
        <house id 2>
            ...
    houses
        <house id>
            title: "some title",
            rooms: ["roomId1", "roomId2", ...]
        <house id 2>
            ...
    rooms
        <house id>
            roomId1
                type: "living",
                objects: ["objId1", "objId2", ...]
            roomId2
                type: "empty"
        <house id 2>
            ...
    objects
        <house id>
            objId1: {type: "chair", color: "red"},
            objId2: {type: "table", color: "white"}
        <house id 2>
            ...
```

So when I want to delete a house, I need to cascade delete all rooms and objects, then the house, then the permissions. And as I said before, deleting goes just fine, but how can I ensure there are no references remaining on the rest of my code to avoid getting permission errors?

```
FIREBASE WARNING: on() or once() for /4437/houses/-JepfRtexB0YI1oBBZzg failed: Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data. 
Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

Thank you

Comment: "a bunch of permission errors on console" -> what errors are you getting? Please click the edit link under your question and add the error message.

Comment: In addition: unless you show us reduce a minimal piece of code that reproduces the problem, it will be pretty difficult to tell you what to change about your code.

Comment: added an example of error message

Comment: Use $destroy(). It's no more polluting your code to get rid of the listeners than it is to create them in the first place. If you want to do that in a central location, which is a great idea, wrap the creation of the synchronized objects and store references to them.